# Unable to pass variable in RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex as shown below

```
const regex = /^.*?\*AUY:(.*?)$/gmi;
```

I am trying to pass the string **AUY** as a variable . I have tried doing the following but it gives an error of incorrect Regular Expression

```
var strreg="^.*?\*"+ID+":(.*?)$";
const regex = new RegExp(strreg,"gmi");
```

Comment: The issue is that you need to use `\\*`, not `\*`, and the error is related to the fact that your expression tries to quantify a quantifier (`*??`).

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with passing the `ID` in as a variable - you're doing that bit right. Your original regex had the same problem. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^.*?*AUY:(.*?)$/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: @Jamiec but if I try to use it without variable it runs good.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tired doing that too but it didn't helped.

Comment: Your original used literal regex syntax (starts/ends with `/`) and with that you dont need to escape characters. When you change to using a string regex and the constructor you need to escape the string. Check the linked duplicate for more info.

Comment: *It didn't helped* - Really? Did you try `var strreg="^.*?\\*"+ID+":(.*?)$";`? Well, let alone you may write it as `var strreg="^[^*]*\\*"+ID+":(.*)";`

Comment: Yup @WiktorStribiżew got that . Thank You